# Convert a meteor-Angular Application to Express JS-Angular Applicaiton

Tags: javascript, angular, express, meteor, automation

Is there any Automatic way or any minimalistic way to Convert an Application where the backend is `meteor` and the frontend is `angular` to backend `Express js` and the frontend is `angular` to `vue js`.

I know I am supposed to explain what I have tried so far, but so far I haven't found any article or any sort of documentation which can guide me to do this work.

The reason why I want to convert the meteor application to something is lite is because the meteor Application is a extremely heavy application.

Do any of you know of any automatic process to Converting this Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are no tools to do this kind of conversion. Without any knowledge of what you have, I would hazard a guess that it is entirely possible to make your app perform better.

Meteor has a built in tool to allow you to look at the bundle size, and see where you need to trim the fat. Then you could use lazy loading to make your app initial load much quicker.

The "weight" is most likely in the Angular front end rather than the Meteor back end. Angular can be very inefficient if there are too many objects in the digest cycle - which equates to things on the screen that depend on each other. This is where I would focus some time, to identify the pages that are heavy, and look at either optimising them or rewriting them.

It will also depend on which version of Angular you are using (there have been many), if it's a bit old, a rewrite may be necessary anyway. If that's the case, you could rewrite in Vue, and keep the Meteor back end.

Comment: thank you for your awesome explanation. It’s helped me a lot to understand where I should put my focus Instead of just trying to change the backend.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with the conversion. Rewriting is often a good idea to fix up design problems anyway.